# How do I create an auto suggestion from a JSON API response?

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

Amazon provides an API to get suggestions for the letters entered:

```
 http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=facebook
```

will give response:

```
["facebook",["facebook","facebook login","facebook.com","facebook credits","facebook gift card","facebook app","facebook messenger","facebook for dummies","facebook en español","facebook phone"],[{"nodes":[{"alias":"mobile-apps","name":"Apps for Android"},{"alias":"stripbooks","name":"Books"},{"alias":"textbooks-tradein","name":"Books Trade-in"},{"alias":"digital-text","name":"Kindle Store"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[]]
```

How do I create auto suggestions from this JSON response using jQuery or PHP?

Comment: You will need to parse this JSON response and re-format it the way you it needs to look to conform with the AutoComplete widget OR use custom rendering of the JSON response. Either way, you've got some work to do. Here's a little reference from the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, and another source: http://thebestsolution.org/customizing-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete/

Comment: i tried for offline autosuggestion but dont know how to do it for json reply ?

Comment: You are `GET`ting this JSON data via an AJAX call to the Amazon site, right?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could either create jsFiddle or post all of your HTML and Javascript here.

Comment: For example, you should be doing something like this to get the returned data:

`$.getJSON('http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete', {search-alias: 'aps', client: 'amazon-search-ui', mkt: '1', q: 'facebook'});`

Comment: okk...then how to append it in a list as suggestions ?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/tK6T5/. This should help with some of the basics. It's late and I have to go to bed. If you're still lost after this, keep hollering!!!

Comment: correct when you wake up ;)

Comment: How is curl a relevant tag? :-p

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/tK6T5/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use the [jqueryui-autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin, then you can set its [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option to a a function which mediates between the format that jqueryui-autocomplete needs and the API Amazon provides. The following should be able to handle the JSONP response based on the JSON you are giving as an example. You can see that the API endpoint you provided supports JSONP by adding a `callback` GET parameter to your example URI. For example, http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=facebook&callback=_ returns the data wrapped in a call to `_()`. jQuery glosses over this with its `dataType: 'jsonp'` option. This is necessary to support cross-site requests, since you are unlikely to be serving your site with an [origin](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454) the same as that of the completion API.

```
/*
 * Connect all <input class="autocomplete"/> to Amazon completion.
 */
jQuery('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    jQuery.ajax('http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete', {
      /* Disable cache breaker; potentially improves performance. */
      cache: true,
      data: {
        client: 'amazon-search-ui',
        mkt: 1,
        'search-alias': 'aps',
        q: request.term
      },
      error: function() {
        /*
         * jquery-autocomplete’s documentation states that response()
         * must be called once per autocomplete attempt, regardless
         * of whether or not the background request completed
         * successfully or not.
         */
        response([]);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        /*
         * Amazon returns an array of different types of
         * autocomplete metadata. The second member is a
         * list of terms the user might be trying to type.
         * This list is compatible with jqueryui-autocomplete.
         */
        response(data[1]);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
  }
});
```

Remember to run this code after the DOM is ready, such as from inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function() { statements_here(); });`.

Comment: btw, using this api has any limits? I mean, if its running from the user's end it shouldn't, but if any webapp is using this, it will definitely run out if the app gets popular, right?

Comment: Though now that this is the future, maybe one's supposed to be fine with CORS?